# Rails errors resets form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems simple, but I can't find anything on it.

I have a link to request a meeting with another user. This produces a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/meetings/new?requestee_id=5
```

The requestee id, and other information in the form are passed to the MeetingController:

```
def create

 requestor = current_user
 @meeting_with_params = meeting_params
 @meeting = Meeting.new(meeting_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @meeting.save
    format.html { redirect_to home_url, notice: 'Your lex was successfully requested! Click Plan Meeting ' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @meeting }
  else
    format.html { render :new, params: @meeting_with_params }
    format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

If there are errors, the url now looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/meetings
```

which means the form will never submit since the requestee_id is not present.

What is right way to have the user see errors, but the url params are never reset?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the last part of this sentence

 "What is right way to have the user see errors, but the url params are never reset?"

Comment: You can do it by ajax submit but you need to show the error from js .

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII the question is, how can the errors be shown, but keeping the url the same. Right now, it takes the params out of he url

Comment: @prakashS Is there a rails way/

Comment: this link to request is from rails? As far as I know (Im a rails begginer) this is no rails url. Maybe there are some mistake.

Comment: @gwalshington i think there is no alternate way .. doing by ajax is right way

Comment: another vote for "do it with ajax", you don't want to change the way rails does it even though I could tell you how you could...

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll that is my question. How to do it with rails, not ajax.

Comment: Can you post the `new` action ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`format.html { render "path/to/new?{@meeting_with_params.to_param}" }`

OR

You can use rails path helpers. You can`rake routes` and find your url's helper path (it looks something like this: edit_user_path, new_user_path)

`format.html { render new_meeting_path(@meeting_with_params) }`

Comment: @gwalshington does this help?

Answer (score 0):

As you are ok to use ajax for this checkout `[https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs](jquery-ujs)`, your form tag has to look something like this:

```
form_for @meeting, data: {remote: true} ...
```